# Find value of list<object> that cause to make true condition using C# and linq

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects which name is `ObjectA` and another list of Objects that name is `ObjectB` like:

```
var result = objectA.any(x=> objectB.contain(x.item));
```

Now my question is: if my condition was true, how can i find value of `ObjectB` which caused that made my condition true?

Comment: var result = objectA.FirstOrDefault(x=> objectB.contain(x.item));

Comment: .... Or if you have multiple elements that might satisfy the condition and you're intrested in all of them then use `Where` instead

Comment: Note that when you're dealing with an instance variable or static class in Visual Studio, assuming you're using VS, you can type "." and it will show you a list of available methods and properties/fields. It's one of the ways of discovering what you can do with an object.

Comment: In tow objects, I have some property that just one of them is the same. that I want to check contain with that property.

Comment: var matches = objectB.Where(b=>objectA.item ==b);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try is:

```
List<ObjectB> sample = new List<ObjectB>();
List<ObjectA> mainList = new List<ObjectA>();
objectB result = sample.FirstOrDefault(ele => mainList.Any(x => ele == x.item);
```

or If you want Multiple Objects then :-

```
  List<objectB> resultList = sample.Where(ele => mainList.Any(x => ele == x.item).ToList();
```

I assumed that `ObjectB` is a representation of list

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha happy to help

Answer (score 1):

A whole plethora of findy routines for your amusement

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence contains no elements.

```
var obj = objectA.FirstOrDefault(x=> objectB.Contains(x.item));
```

---

[Enumerable.First Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence.

```
var obj = objectA.First(x=> objectB.Contains(x.item));
```

---

[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. Each element's
>   index is used in the logic of the predicate function.

```
var objs = objectA.Where(x=> objectB.Contains(x.item));
```

---

[List.IndexOf Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of
>   the first occurrence within the entire List.

```
var obj = objectA.IndexOf(obj);
```

---

[Enumerable.Last Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the last element of a sequence

---

[Enumerable.LastOrDefault Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the last element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

---

[Enumerable.Intersect Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

IEnumerable<int> both = id1.Intersect(id2);

foreach (int id in both)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 26
 30
*/
```

---

[Enumerable.Except Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx))

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
    Console.WriteLine(number);

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 2
 2.1
 2.3
 2.4
 2.5
*/
```

Comment: Nice one for all the explanation sir.

Comment: No. if your list was not the same type, except not working.

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha that's an extremely strange comment, what on earth do you mean

Comment: @TheGeneral This is easy, in your sample used tow objects array of double, now if your objects didn't same type, the extension method of expect not work.

lucifer at upper than here has a best answer.

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha Anyway, your best answer taught you how to eat a fish, i taught you how to fish, good luck

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with iterating the `IEnumerable` multiple times.

This is, performance and simplicity wise, a nice approach for you.

```
var result = objectA.Where(x => objectB.contain(x.item)).ToList();

if (result.Any())
{
    // use the already enumerated objects inside "result" list
}
```